# How save a Date from Google App Script to a Timestamp in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore

Can anyone help mw with writing a timestamp from google script to firestore. When I use "new Date()" in google script, it store as an empty map in firestore. If I stringify the Date, it stores as a String firestore, But i need this attribute to store a Timestamp.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM3MW.png)

[Storing as JavaScript Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULKAw.png)

Comment: How do you write from Google App Script to Firestore?? Through the REST API? Please share your code.

Comment: Have you tried saving it inside a JavaScript object? i.e. var timeObj = {}; timeObj.timeStmp = new Date();

Comment: @Stykes Saving inside JavaScript Object isnt working either. see screenshot above –

Comment: Could you solve your problem @AbdurraheemAbdulhakeem? If yes can you share the solution please

Answer (score 1):

To save as a timestamp, just make sure your date is actually a `date`, and not a `String`. I used `DATEVALUE` to convert my `String` to a date, then I let [this library (FirestoreGoogleAppsScript)](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript) to take care of the rest.